# SSIS production package doesn't show some changes

Tags: scripting, ssis

I have an SSIS package that detects test domains from a data set being passed through the pipeline. I use a Scripting Component to send an e-mail notification listing the domains that have been marked as test domains. When I first posted the package with the notification, it sent a separate e-mail for each domain, after receiving to many e-mails, I changed the script to send a single e-mail with a list of the test domains. However each time I publish this update, it continues to send a single notification for each test domain.

Things I have looked into:

- The content of the first e-mail and the second e-mail are different. So I did a "Find in Files" search in Notepad++ to see if I could find where the original e-mail content might be stored. There were no results found containing the original content.
- I have disable the step which sends the notifications and published the package. This results in no notification e-mails being sent. However when I re-enable the step and publish, the original notifications sending a single e-mail for each test domains starts again.
- I have tried dropping the SQL job that executes this package and recreating it but still the original notifications come through.

So with no trace of the original content even found on the production server, I do not know where this is coming from. I don't see anything about where the content could be cached, but even if it was being cached, then when I disabled the notification step, it would have still sent the notifications.

I am worried that if this can't be fixed, then does this mean there are other packages that are not being fully updated?

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

This is pretty much how the Scripting Component is setup...

```
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

Private strDomains As String = String.Empty

Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
    MyBase.PreExecute()
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
    If strDomains.Length > 0 Then
        Dim myHtmlMessage As MailMessage
        Dim mySmtpClient As SmtpClient
        Dim strMessageBody As New StringBuilder

        strMessageBody.AppendLine("The listed domains have blah blah blah...")
        strMessageBody.Append(strDomains)
        strMessageBody.AppendLine(String.Empty)
        strMessageBody.AppendLine("Love and Kisses,")
        strMessageBody.AppendLine("Your Loving ETL Package")
        strMessageBody.AppendLine(Variables.PackageName)

        myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage("ETLNotices@company.com", "me@company.com", "Possible Test Domains", strMessageBody.ToString)

        mySmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.company.com")
        mySmtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        mySmtpClient.Send(myHtmlMessage)
    End If

    MyBase.PostExecute()
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    Dim str As New StringBuilder
    str.AppendLine(strDomains)
    str.AppendFormat("{0}", Row.DomainName)

    strDomains = str.ToString
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

I have some questions:

I guess you are using looping mechanism in your script task to iterate through all the domains ; find test ones among them; append them to a string and at the end send out an email. Is this correct?

Are you sending the mail in the script or created a separate Send Mail task?

Is the body of the your mail coming from some variable from config file?

Comment: You are correct in me adding the domains together in a variable and then build out an email in the scripting component. The email is also sent from the scripting component. The email is very short and the body is hard coded in the Scripting Component and not stored in a variable anywhere else.

Comment: Ok can you attach the script here. I guess i need to see it to find the cause behind the issue. EDIT: Oh you already attached the script. Let me have a look.